# Why does the same app have different behavior on different server

Tags: php, progress-bar, windows-server-2016

I'm working on my first Laravel app, that at some stage loops through a large amount of data and I temporary added a primitive progress bar so I can have an idea how long it will take to finish...

It is working as it should on Win 8.1 XAMPP, but when I move it to Windows server 2016 (IIS + PHP 7.3.1 + MySQL 5.5) , the page just keeps loading, then suddenly it's 100%... or it the whole process fails, but that's an other problem.

Here is my primitive code:

1. create the progress bar html

   ```
   echo'<div class="w3-container  w3-display-middle" style="width:75%">
   <p id="progress2text" style="visibility: hidden;">Pre-analyzing</p>
   <div class="w3-border" id="progress2" style="height:24px; visibility: hidden;"></div><br>
   <p>Analyzing - Do not close the page! You will be redirected when it is done...</p>
   <div class="w3-border" id="progress3" style="height:24px;"></div>
   ```

   ';
2. making the progress bar visible

   ```
   echo '<script language="javascript">
               document.getElementById("progress2text").style.visibility = "visible";
               document.getElementById("progress2").style.visibility = "visible";   
       </script>';
   ```
3. updating process bar at the beginning of every loop

   ```
   while(){
   //caluclating $percent here 
           echo '
           <script language="javascript">
               document.getElementById("progress2").innerHTML="<div class=\"w3-green w3-center\" style=\"height:24px;width:'.$percent.'%\">'.$percent.'%</div>";   
           </script>';
   }
   ```

Thank you.

Comment: That is not how you pass data from PHP to your frontend. Essentially, what happens here is your PHP script renders entire page full of inline scripts with different percent values and then gives it to your browser once it's finished. Then browser starts executing those scripts all at once.

Comment: Also I suggest you change tags for this question. It has nothing to do with `laravel`. but features `php` and `javascript` in general.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Where can I set how php should render the page? About Laravel... I'm doing this in a controller, before redirect to a view. And the reason is to get an idea of the progress instead of just watching the page loading before the redirect happens.

Comment: I turned off output buffering in php.ini, but doesn't help. However in XAMPP it works with output buffering as well. What other settings can affect this?